# 2nd (landscape) screen of application turns portrait in iOS6

Tags: ipad, ios6, landscape, regression, uiinterfaceorientation

I 'm working on an iPad app in landscape mode only that worked nicely under iOS5 and under.
On iOS6, the 2nd screen (login screen) turns suddenly in portrait mode.
What parameters should i check?

Answer (score 0):

check below methods for it.

// need for above ios6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

return NO; // YES or NO as per your requirement
}

- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ParthDubai, i solved the issue in adding 
`[window setRootViewController:viewController];`
in AppDelegate